# Чтение excel файла в Datagridview и импорт в sql сервер - C#

Tags: sql, excel, datagridview, импорт

Делаю импорт в Datagridview с Excel. потом эти данные хочу сохранить в SQL базу, сохраняет, но в конце выдаёт ошибку:

Must declare the scalar variable "@ID".

можно как то это решить ?

```
private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 6;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            string constring = @"Data Source=192.168.0.3\VADCASQL;Initial Catalog=dbexcel;User Id=sa;Password=***;";
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO test VALUES(@ID, @Pavadinimas, @Kiekis, @Darbuotojas, @Papildymas, @Akcija)", con))
                {
                        if(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value==null)
                        {                                 
                            MessageBox.Show("XXXXXX");
                            //con.Close();
                           // this.Close();

                            //con.Open();
                            //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            //con.Close();

                        }
                        else
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);

                        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value == null)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pavadinimas", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = DBNull.Value);
                        }
                        else
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pavadinimas", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);

                        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value == null)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kiekis", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = DBNull.Value);
                        }
                        else
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kiekis", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);

                        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value == null)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Darbuotojas", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = DBNull.Value);
                        }
                        else
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Darbuotojas", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);

                        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value == null)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Papildymas", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = DBNull.Value);
                        }
                        else
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Papildymas", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);

                        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value == null)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Akcija", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = DBNull.Value);
                        }
                        else
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Akcija", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);                           



                        con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
```

Comment: Сэр, вынесите создание команды с параметрами из цикла (это нужно делать только один раз), а в цикле оставьте только присвоение значений параметрам (с корректной обработкой значения NULL)  и все сразу станет хорошо.

Comment: Сохранило в базе но выкинуло такую ошибку: The parameterized query '(@ID nvarchar(4000),@Pavadinimas nvarchar(4000),@Kiekis nvarchar' expects the parameter '@ID', which was not supplied.

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас выложу схему кода как надо днлать

Comment: Спасибо, жду с нетерпением :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если приведете в порядок Ваш код по такой схеме

```
void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /*
    ...
    */

    //Один раз создаем комманду с параметрами вне циклов
    string constring = @"Data Source=192.168.0.3\VADCASQL;Initial Catalog=dbexcel;User Id=sa;Password=***;";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);

    //Окрываете Connection в Вашем случае это можно сделать один раз на весь массив из dataGridView1
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO test VALUES(@ID, @Pavadinimas, @Kiekis, @Darbuotojas, @Papildymas, @Akcija)", con);

        SqlParameter prmId = cmd.Parameters.Add("Id", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);

         /*
         SqlParameter prmPavadinimas = cmd.Parameters.Add("Id", SqlDbType.Ваш тип);

         и так далее для всех параметров ....
         */

        //Перенос данных из dataGridView1 в базу
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
             if(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value !=null) 
             {
                 prmId.Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value; //Если нужно то делаем Guid из Rows[i].Cells[0].Value
             }
             else
             {
                 //Нет Id 
                  MessageBox.Show("XXXXXX");
                 continue;
             }


             if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value == null)
             {
                   prmPavadinimas.Value = DBNull.Value;
             }
             else
             {
                   prmPavadinimas.Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);  //Возможно, что здесь потребуется явное приведение к типу
             }

             //И так далее для всех параметров
            /*
            .....
             */
            //Выполнение команды (Его лучше сделать в отдельном try{} catch{}
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch(Exception ee)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
            }

        }
    }
    catch( Exception ee)
    {
         //Обрабатываете возможное исключение при открытии
         MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

То все будет работать. В вашей версии Вы не создавали параметры, которая требовала созданная Вами команда, для нулевых значений параметров

Comment: @Вадим , если я Вам помог, то не забудьте проголосовать за мой ответ :)

Comment: Обезательно проголосую, НЕСохранило вылазит таблица: Failed convert parameter Value from a Double to a Guid

Comment: Супер сохранило, исправил УniqueIdentifier на INT и всё заработало. Огромное спасибо ВЫ ГЕНИЙ !

Comment: @Вадим Пожалуйста, рад что помог :)

Comment: А как Вы @Александр Муксимов думаете, можно будет импортировать без оодного столбика,  тот столбик в sql primary key и автоматически номер добавляет (происходит нумерация)

Comment: Попробовал сам. Не даёт сохранить. Нужно все столбики прописывать, и убирать автоматическое нумерование.Или может есть какое нибудь решение ?

Comment: @Вадим сейчас я в "лесу" и пишу с мобилы, поэтому могу ошибиться, но по моему при автоинкрементном ключевом поле его просто не нужно указывать в INSERT. Сам я предпочитаю в качестве ключевого поля Guid и формирую их сам на клиенте. Выбор Guid, как ключевого поля избавляет от проблем слияния нескольких баз в одну, а формирование на клиенте позволяет легко выполнять предварительную обработку и с несколькими таблицами и сохранение результатов в одной транзакции.

Comment: Ок, попробую. Уберу нумерацию, сдею guid. Отпишусь о результате

Comment: Убрал авто нумерацию,сделал uniqueidentifier а в C# guid и всё супер. Спасибо

Comment: помогите пожалуйста с этой проблемой: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633640/Нажав-на-значение-строку-из-одного-datagridview-поиск-в-другом-datagridview