# Нажав на значение (строку) из одного DataGridView поиск в другом DataGridView

Tags: поиск, datagridview

Всем привет.
Есть 2 DataGridView в одном только дата, а во втором дата и много других столбиков.
Нужно при нажатии в 1 DataGridView на дату отображались все данные по выбраной дате во 2 DataGridView.
Что делаю не так ?

```
private void Planavimas_DataSet_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: данная строка кода позволяет загрузить данные в таблицу "pard_planasDataSet.Pardavimo_men". При необходимости она может быть перемещена или удалена.
        this.pardavimo_menTableAdapter.Fill(this.pard_planasDataSet.Pardavimo_men);
        // TODO: данная строка кода позволяет загрузить данные в таблицу "pard_planasDataSet.Plan_prekes". При необходимости она может быть перемещена или удалена.
        this.plan_prekesTableAdapter.Fill(this.pard_planasDataSet.Plan_prekes);
        planprekesBindingSource.Sort = "Pavadinimas ASC";          

    }

private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value == null)
                 { planprekesBindingSource.Filter = string.Empty; }
            else
                planprekesBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("[Data] Like'" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "%'");

        }

    }
```

Comment: я постараюсь, но не уверен, что у меня будет доступ к ЭВМ, до завтрашнего утра

Comment: @Александр Муксимов я буду ждать :)

Answer (score 1):

Вот решил проблему:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value == null)
                 { planprekesBindingSource.Filter = string.Empty; }
            else
                planprekesBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("[Data] Like'" + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value + "%'");

        }
```

А как должна выглядеть строка если нужно несколько фильтров одновременно. например остаётся тот что сейчас есть и + фильтр с textbox и ещё один с combobox ?